# Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Error I'm getting when I start my spring boot application.

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ;
> nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException:
> Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global
> threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:86) ~[?:2.9 (09-29-2022)]
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
> ~[?:1.8.0] at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
> ~[?:1.8.0] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
> ~[?:1.8.0] at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13] Caused by:
> org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ;
> nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException:
> Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global
> threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.
> at
> org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:371)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1] at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] ... 19 more Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology:
> Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe
> to at least one source topic or global table. at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TopologyMetadata.getNumStreamThreads(TopologyMetadata.java:215)
> ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:?] at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:916)
> ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:?] at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:845)
> ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:?] at
> org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:751)
> ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:?] at
> org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:349)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1] at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28] ... 19 more

code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafkaStreams;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamsConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.application.id}")
    private String applicationId;


    @Bean
    public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfig) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream < String, String > kStream = builder.stream("retry-events", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        // Define a custom ObjectMapper for JSON parsing
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Use mapValues to parse JSON and extract the timestamp
        kStream = kStream.mapValues(value - > {
            try {
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(value);
                long timestamp = jsonNode.get("timestamp").asLong();
                long tenMinutesAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() / 60000; // Current time in minutes
                if (timestamp <= tenMinutesAgo) {
                    return value; // Keep messages that match the criteria
                } else {
                    return null; // Filter out messages that don't match the criteria
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }).filter((key, value) - > value != null); // Remove messages that failed parsing

        kStream.to("output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        return kafkaStreams;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `@EnableKafkaStreams` makes my application start without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Spring Kafka Streams you don't need to define and create a KafkaStreams bean. This will be done by Spring for you, however you do need to give it some sort of Topology to run, as you have noticed.

The easiest way to configure this is to have a bean which would be of type KStream<K,V> (whatever Key, Value you chose here), and inject it with StreamBuilder.

This would look something like this:

```
@Bean
public KStream<String, String> topologyBuilder(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder, YourTopologyClass topo) {
    return topo.processStream(streamsBuilder);
}
```

And your YourTopologyClass would look something like this:

```
class YourTopologyClass {
    
    public KStream<String, String> processStream(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
         // Your topology construction goes here

     }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting same error after making changes like above code.
`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.`

I've 'KafkaStreamsConfiguration' class which has all the properties defined.
I created a new class named 'KafkaStreamsService' which has topologyBuilder
and created new class called topologyClass which has my logic

Comment: Are you still returning KafkaStreams as a bean?

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're asking..

Comment: You configuration class returns a bean of type KafkaStreams, are you still doing that?

Comment: oh, yeah. I removed that and tried but still getting same error